# How to make a module accessible for all applications including GAE deployment process

Tags: python, google-app-engine, deployment, module, gae-module

I have a Python module containing some utils that all my GAE applications may use. I created it myself. It is n a separate folder and I sometimes want to update its code, make refactorings etc. Every application I create, can take use functions from this module. Now I need to copy the module folder somewhere inside an application and import its functions. It's an ordinary procedure, nothing fancy. When I make some updates to the code of the module, I then need to overwrite this module if it is already imported in the application. Then I just deploy the application with GAE utility and all works fine. The question is - Is that possible to not have many copies of the module in every application having to overwrite them all every time I update some code inside that, but have one copy in one place and automatically import it from there? I know I can copy the module code somewhere Python searches for modules. Though, I still need to copy this module folder into the application when I deploy it into GAE environment. So, I need one copy of a module accessible for all my application when they are on my local PC and need to have that folder copied into the app when I deploy it. Is there a good and nice solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can store your module in a directory outside all your GAE apps and then create a symbolic link to that directory inside all the GAE apps directories. `appcfg.py` will follow the symbolic link. Quoting from the [Python SDK docs](http://code.google.com/intl/it/appengine/docs/python/runtime.html#Pure_Python):

> If you make a symbolic link to a module's directory in your application directory, appcfg.py will follow the link and include the module in your app.

Comment: Wow, I never knew I could use an absolutely different way. It works like a charm. Now it seems that I get rid of additional routines with copying and overwriting files. Thanks!

Comment: @Sergey you are welcome. ;) Don't forget to accept the answer if you feel that your problem is now solved :D

Comment: You could also use version control - for example, a git subrepo.